# how to search for an id from a group of id using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

in my table i have a feild **user_ids**. the user_ids feilds containeing the values like **12,45,78,95,21,78,98**

what i need is i need an **mysql** query that search for a specific id(for ex:45) in the feild.

i used **like** operator but its not working as i expected. for ex: when i search for **5** its return tru, but the **id 5** not in the list.

i would like to know is there any default function is available in **mysql**.

could you pls help me...

my query.

```
SELECT * FROM `FRIENDSLIST` WHERE `USERS_ID` LIKE '%'.$ID.'%';
```

NB: i dont know whether this question meets standard,pls dont do down vote. pls help me....

Comment: Please include in your question the query you have tried.

Comment: You shouldn't store all `user_ids` in one field, but create another table instead wich contains `user_id` and `mytable_id` fields.

Comment: @Athur. actually you are write. but im not in a situation to do it as im working with alredy defined table. if i go for this option i need to change allmost all scenarios and i dont have the permission to do it... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also works:

```
select * from FRIENDSLIST where find_in_set( $ID, USERS_ID ) <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks so much @rgin. i got what im looking for. i didnt here about this function before :).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Where ',' + MyField + ',' Like '%,' + MySearchString + ',%'
```

The problem is that you're thinking of it as IDs, but it's just a string. So when you search for '5' in '12,45,78,95,21,78,98' it finds it in the 5 of the 45. If you surround with commas then it searches for ',45,' in ',12,45,78,95,21,78,98,' and finds it, but is you look for ',5,' it won't match, as desired.

you also need to add commas at the beginning and end to be able to math the first and last IDs.

Comment: What happens when you search for 98?

Comment: The 98 should also work because the statement adds leading and trailing commas to the string in which you search. so the search becomes Where ',12,45,78,95,21,78,98,' like ',98,' and it matches. Sorry for all the edits. Sleepy!

Comment: And sorry again, meant Where ',12,45,78,95,21,78,98,' like '%,98,%'

Answer (score 0):

As per your data simpler way is to search with comma as like ',45,'.

But better way is it split them based on comma and matching to it.